# Version 9 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 9 would receive version 10

Tags: android, google-play

I published a new version for my app with version 8. It published successfully. Then I realized there is a fatal bug, I immediately corrected it and tried to publish it with version 9. However, it saved it as draft and cannot publish it. I tried to delete the draft, also it cannot be done. I deactivated version 8 (buggy one) and uploaded new one, it is also saved as draft. So, I couldn't publish new one over version 8. People are still downloading buggy version and I could not do anything. Can you please help? Here is the picture
http://postimg.org/image/iokyc9js7/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, firstly you should Deactivate the APK versioned 8, then the button "Publish" will be enabled again. You can click that button to publish your new APK. It works for me.